# How to change the aspect ratio with drawing tool?

Tags: plotting, image, interactive, slideshows

I'm drawing an image in editing an slide show with the drawing tools. But the aspect ratio of the created drawing seems fixed and not changeable with mouse dragging the border and corner as in other applications. How can I change this ratio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+drag the corner handles of the orange frame to change the aspect ratio.  (You may need to double click to get the thick gray editing frame first.)

[image]

[image]

**Note:** if resizing individual elements <kbd>Shift</kbd> operates in reverse: holding it constrains the aspect ratio, while not holding it allows free resizing.

You can resize the canvas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+drag and continue drawing:

[image]

---

- The above operations are covered in [Resizing, Cropping, and Adding Margins to Graphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsLayout.html#509267359)
- See the main [Editing *Mathematica* Graphics Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EditingWolframLanguageGraphicsOverview.html) for many other helpful examples.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there any other shortcut so that I can change the size of the canvas without changing the ratio of the elements in the canvas?

Comment: @xgdgsc You can Ctrl+drag to resize the canvas, which can also be used to crop a graphic or image.