# Exporting an overlay of two plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, overlay

I have a ListLinePlot and I'm trying to place a close-up of a specific range in the ListLinePlot. Using overlay I solved this problem with:

```
Overlay[{p1, Item[Show[p2], Alignment -> {-.7, .6}]}]
```

This results in something like the following image:

[image: Overlay example]

But I can't select this image and export it. I can do "Print Selection as" and save as pdf, but this rasterizes the image. I want the same resolution as with a normal graphics environment. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Overlay.html) preserves unrasterized copies of its constituent Graphics it is rasterized by the Front End for the purpose of display.  Therefore I do not believe that you can use `Overlay` for this purpose.

However, I believe you can use [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html) and [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html):

```
p1 = Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}];
p2 = BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}];

Show[p1,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Epilog -> Inset[Show[p2, ImageSize -> 150], Scaled[{.6, .6}]]
]
```

[image]

You can also inset graphics manually.  See:

- [How to insert a plot into another plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/how-to-insert-a-plot-into-another-plot/14565#14565)
- [How to change the aspect ratio with drawing tool?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32845/121)

Comment: Thanks, this works! FYI I used ```Show[p1, Epilog -> Inset[p2, {65, 300}]]``` in my case. I've seen that it can be done manually, but figured it could be done in mathematica code :).

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Export[]` when you cannot select outputs in the Front End.

```
Overlay[{p1, Item[Show[p2], Alignment -> {-.7, .6}]}]
Export["graphics.pdf",%]
```

saves the graphics as PDF in your current working directory. No rasterization happens.
 This technique can also be used for output of `GraphicsRow`, `GraphicsColumn`, and `GraphicsGrid` where you cannot select whole the graphics.

Comment: You're right!  Very interesting.

Comment: Yes! Tetsuo's solution is much better!